# Optional parts of regex pattern in vba

Tags: regex, vba

I am trying to build regex pattern for the text like that

```
numb contra: 1.29151306 number mafo: 66662308
numb contra 1.30789668number mafo 60.046483
numb contra/ 1.29154056 number mafo: 666692638
numb contra     137459625
mafo: 666692638
mafo: 666692638 numb contra/ 1.29154056
```

Here's the pattern I could build

```
contra?.\s+?(\d+\.?\d+)(.+mafo.?\s+(\d+\.?\d+))?
```

It works fine for all the lines except the last one. How can I implement all the possibilities to include the last line too?

Please have a look at this link
https://regex101.com/r/pSThAU/1
All is OK as for contra but not as for mafo

Comment: Use alternation, `contra?.\s+?(\d*\.?\d+)(.+mafo.?\s+(\d*\.?\d+))?|mafo.?\s+(\d*\.?\d+)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. In that case of your pattern, will it be possible to extract each number to a column (especially the last one) as I tried the pattern on regex101 and the number in the last line appeared in different color. How can I make the two parts of contra and mafo optional and at the same time to be easy when using the code to separate to the proper column?

Comment: Tip `contra?` only makes the last char (`a`) optional. If you want the whole word optional, use a parenthesis: `(contra)?`.

Comment: In fact, I am lost. I need the regex pattern to focus on the strings `contra` and `mafo` and I need the numbers related to each. The problem is that I have a lot of possibilties: may be have the two contra at first followed by mafo, or the two mafo at first followed by contra, and sometimes just conta and not mafo, and sometimes just mafo not contra. So I am trying to find a way to absorb all these possibilties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the key here is to make your regexp do less and your vba do more.  What I think I see here is *either* the word 'mafo' or 'contra' and a number following.  Don't know what order or whether each is present or how many times.  So you can scan each of your strings for ALL occurrences with a regexp like this:

```
(?:^|[^A-Z])(?:(mafo)|(contra))[^A-Z]\s*(\d*\.?\d+)
```

Then process it with some VBA code like this that I created in Excel:

```
Sub BreakItUp()
Dim rg As RegExp, scanned As MatchCollection, eachMatch As Match, i As Long, col As Long

Set rg = New RegExp
rg.Pattern = "(?:^|[^A-Z])(?:(mafo)|(contra))[^A-Z]\s*(\d*\.?\d+)"
rg.IgnoreCase = True
rg.Global = True
i = 1
Do While (Not IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value))
    Set scanned = rg.Execute(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value)
    col = 2
    For Each eachMatch In scanned
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, col).Value = eachMatch.SubMatches(0) & eachMatch.SubMatches(1)
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, col + 1).Value2 = "'" & eachMatch.SubMatches(2)
        col = col + 2
    Next eachMatch
    i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

That MatchCollection object will get one item for each Match that occurs and the subMatches array contains each capturing group.  You should be able write your own logic within this processing loop to interpret what was extracted.  When I ran it on your data it created all the fields in blue:
[image]

Notice I added a line to your data that had two contra entries and one mafo and it found all the occurrences.  You should be able to modify this to interpret the meanings.

Comment: Amazing. Can you please add the explanation of the regex pattern to learn from you?

Comment: OK - The first parens contain `(?:^|[^A-Z])` - this is a bit of a hack because VBA does not have lookbehinds.  It's there to make sure we do not match xyzzymafo: 1.3.  The (?: tells the regexp scanner to not capture that as a numbered group.  The next parens are `(?:(mafo)|(contra))` which says accept mafo (in capture group 1) OR contra (in capture group 2).  Then `[^A-Z]\s*` is some non-alpha followed by zero or more spaces.  Finally, `(\d*\.?\d+)` is a basic number capturing pattern into capture group 3.  It won't accept 123456. as a valid number, but everything else should be OK

Comment: I would not complicate the Regexp.  Instead, as you iterate through the MatchCollection put in something like `If IsEmpty(match.subMatches(0)) Then contradigits = match.subMatches(2) Else mafodigits = match.subMatches(2) End If`.  then when you get to the end of the MatchCollection you'll have them sorted out.  But only you can provide the extra logic to interpret what one without the other actually means.

Comment: Last question: I have another term of mafo which is `kht`. How can I implement both in the regex pattern?. Just one of them will be existing in the text.

Comment: Can you please have a look at this link https://regex101.com/r/cB36RO/1 I couldn't know why the numbers before the decimal point is not included?